# RTAB-MAP Android version , adding ros inputs/outputs

Tags: ros, android, rtabmap-ros

I want to know if someone have done any work on RTAB-MAP Android, I'm trying to add ROS input/output to the Android version but maybe its a too big challenge for me so I try to find someone to help. I think it helps a lot since with that kind of functions Android devices can be used as a full ROS sensor.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anyone integrating ROS to rtabmap's android app. A place to start for ROS1 would be to look about how they built ros for android in this project: https://github.com/Intermodalics/tango_ros

Other links for ROS2:

- https://roscon.ros.org/2018/presentations/ROSCon2018_ROS2%20for%20Android,%20iOS%20and%20Universal%20Windows%20Platform.pdf
- https://github.com/ros2-java/ros2_java

Ideally, if you can build `rtabmap_conversions` and `rtabmap_msgs` libraries, they could be included in the android app to "easily" (well, would have to check how it is done in `rtabmap_slam/rtabmap` node) convert the internal rtabmap data to the ros messages.

One caveat from my experience with `tango_ros` is that it may be not obvious how to synchronize the timestamps coming for the phone with an external computer running other ros nodes.